# Managing Jenkins Log Parser Rule

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, hudson-plugins

When I have Jenkins Log Parser enabled with below scenario

1. In Jenkins log if "No such file or directory" make Job unstable. My build finds this string as part of some failure, then
2. I do some work around for above error to complete the job success. and I echo "All completed successfully" at the end.
3. On the Job > "Console output (build log) parsing". Have enabled "Mark build Unstable on Warning"

Right now since the parse finds "No such file or directory" and parser config marks the build as unstable for this strings. Which is expected behavior

Is there a way to mark the job as success after finding "All jobs are complete"?

**shell build step sample script**

```
set +x
echo "rm: cannot remove directory. No such file or directory"
echo "All jobs are complete"
```

**Log parser rule**

```
warning /No such file or directory/
info /All jobs are complete/
```

Comment: Yes, tried that.  No luck. Even tried exit 0

Comment: I think it isn't possible with the Log Parser.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Shell build step in Jenkins v2.26 and above provides an [option](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-23786?focusedCommentId=371276&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-371276) for user to set a specific exit code to mark the build as unstable. When the exit code matches, the build is marked as unstable.

You can set any exit code to mark the build as unstable. When the workaround in your step 2 fails, you can exit with your predefined exit code. This way the build is marked as unstable only when your workaround fails.